# Output a String in a Dialog

Tags: c#, string, dialog, output

I want to know how i can Print the String in Dialog. I dont want to print out  the String in the Console.
So i have this Code:

```
private void info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    // Solution Exxplorer Rechtsklick add text file
    string line = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Bedienungsanleitung.txt"); 
    Console.Write(line);   
}
```

I have already tried differents solutions which i found on the internet.
Can anyone tell me what dialog i need?

Comment: if it is `WinForms`,  `MessageBox.Show(line);` probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not much text, you can use a `MessageBox`, otherwise, if there is a lot of text, you should use a custom dialog.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
private void info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Bedienungsanleitung.txt"); // Solution Exxplorer Rechtsklick add text file

    MessageBox.Show(line);
}
```

Comment: If it is a console application, you first need to add System.Windows.Form reference.

Comment: Good point.  Since his example looked like a click event handler, I assumed it wasn't a console application.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in a console application first you must add the reference for System.Windows.Forms to your solution.To do this you can use the reference sub folder in the solution explorer and right click on it then click add reference.In there select Framework and under this tab you will see System.Windows.Forms and select it.

[image]

After you do this go back to the code and then put this at the top of the class where you can see the using statements

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;
```

In MessageBox.Show() , I can see there are 21 different ways (overloading) to use this .Show() method in .Net Framework 4.5, may be in other versions as well.That means you can customize. One use full signature that I prefer to use is

> MessageBox.Show("Message", "Title of the dialog", MessageBoxButtons,
>   MessageBoxIcon);

Here you can see a valid example

```
     MessageBox.Show("Do you need to save before exit ?","Select the Option",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Another important fact related to MessageBox is DialogResult. We can use this one to check conditions in our code.

```
       private void Exit()
       {
            DialogResult answer= null;

            answer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you need to quit ?\nAll unsaved data will be lost.","Exit Confirmation!",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
            { 
                //Do something if the user wants to exit
            }
            else
            {
                //Do something if user don't want to exit

            }
        }
```

Output of this will look like this

[image]